# Increasing a datetime field with queryset.update

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-orm

My model looks like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    end_time = DateTimeField()
```

and this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
m=MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
m.end_time += timedelta(seconds=34)
m.save()
```

but I want to do it with update() to avoid race conditions:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).update(end_time=F('end_time')+timedelta(seconds=34))
```

but it doesn't work. Is this possible with the django ORM or is raw SQL the only option?

Comment: For what it is worth, I was able to reproduce this error in my machine. I am using Django 1.2.3, Python 2.6.2 and MySQL 5.0.75-0ubuntu10.5 (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

This is completely possible.  Not sure if you're looking at a cached value for your end_time, but here is a test I just ran:

```
>>> e = Estimate.objects.get(pk=17)
>>> e.departure_date
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 12, 0, 1, 8)
>>> Estimate.objects.filter(pk=17).update(departure_date=F('departure_date')+timedelta(seconds=34))
1
>>> e.departure_date
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 12, 0, 1, 8)
>>> e = Estimate.objects.get(pk=17)
>>> e.departure_date
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 12, 0, 1, 42)
```

Comment: When I do it, I get an error: ``Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '0 0:0:34'`` full traceback here: http://pastebin.com/n67WkwWK