# How to increment the year on a datetimefield in Django with update()?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

Is there a way to increment the year on filtered objects using the update() method?

I am using:

```
python 2.6.5
django 1.2.1 final
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41
```

I know it's possible to do something like this:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
for event in Event.objects.filter(end_date__lt=today).iterator():
    event.start_date = festival.start_date + datetime.timedelta(365)
    event.end_date = festival.end_date + datetime.timedelta(365)
    event.save()
```

However, in some cases, I would prefer to use the update() method.

```
# This does not work..

Event.objects.all().update(
            start_date=F('start_date') + datetime.timedelta(365),
            end_date=F('end_date') + datetime.timedelta(365)
            )
```

With the example above, I get:

```
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '365 0:0:0'
```

The sql query it's trying to make is:

```
UPDATE `events_event` SET `start_date` = `events_event`.`start_date` + 365 days, 0:00:00, `end_date` = `events_event`.`end_date` + 365 days, 0:00:00
```

I found something in the mysql guide, but this is raw sql!

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2008-12-15', INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Any idea?

Comment: There seems to be an open ticket with a patch: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10154

Answer (score 2):

One potential cause of *"Warning: Data truncated for column X"* exception is the use of non-whole day values for the timedelta being added to the  **DateField** - it is fine in python, but fails when written to the mysql db. If you have a **DateTimeField**, it works too, since the precision of the persisted field matches the precision of the timedelta.

I.e.:

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> from myapp.models import MyModel
>>> [field for field in MyModel._meta.fields if field.name == 'valid_until'][0]
<django.db.models.fields.DateField object at 0x3d72fd0>
>>> [field for field in MyModel._meta.fields if field.name == 'timestamp'][0]
<django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField object at 0x43756d0>
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).update(valid_until=F('valid_until') + timedelta(days=3))
1L
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).update(valid_until=F('valid_until') + timedelta(days=3.5))
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
Warning: Data truncated for column 'valid_until' at row 1
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(pk=1).update(timestamp=F('timestamp') + timedelta(days=3.5))
1L
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick but ugly:

```
>>> a.created.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=2, tm_min=35, tm_se
c=14, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=307, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> time = list(a.created.timetuple())
>>> time[0] = time[0] + 1
>>> time
[2001, 11, 2, 2, 35, 14, 3, 307, -1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

yourdate = datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 4, 10, 14, 54, 518749)
yourdate += relativedelta(years=+1)
```

Relativedelta takes many time arguments, from seconds to years...

Comment: The problem isn't calculating the extra year. The advantage of using django's update is that the original date isn't fetched out of the database. Your suggestion is similar to what @louis suggested at the top of his question - get the date out of the db, alter it and save it back. This requires two queries instead of one.

Comment: Sorry for that... One un-possible solution might be using F to reasign the value, but i guess thats not possible for date fields... Here is the doc for F: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: [Increasing a datetime field with queryset.update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843250/increasing-a-datetime-field-with-queryset-update) ? I also remember successfully using queryset .update() with timedelta with MySQL backend.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am still getting, Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '365 0:0:0'