# Django - replacing year in DateTimeField

Tags: django, date

With this:
            `mb = self.birthdate.replace(year=date.today.year)`
It gives this:

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'year'
```

It is possible to replace year?

Comment: Can you present the question better? This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093118/how-to-increment-the-year-on-a-datetimefield-in-django-with-update

Comment: I need to replace year just for counting person age. Do not need save cahnges to database.

Comment: what is birthdate is it a datetime object?

Comment: birthdate = models.DateTimeField()

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct line is:

```
mb = self.birthdate.replace(year=date.today().year)
```

date.year is a method not a attribute

[datetime.date.today](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today)

Comment: I wrote this one hour ago:
should be date.today().year - but thanks.